# Having trouble making this PHP curl put request to work

Tags: php, rest, curl, put

I'm trying to make a put request to my server, but, nothing is happening when I call it. Here's what I have:

```
$url = ("http://my.server/api/");
$data = array("{\"bri\": 254, \"on\": true,\"bri\": 10}" => $a);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));

 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 if(!$response) {
return false;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest reading http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php But for starters, you need to redo your first two lines. (remove the '()' from the url, and for the array, make an actual array in the correct format `"key" => "value", "key" => "value"` etc...

Comment: There's no such thing as "nothing happens". There are, however, things like `curl_error($ch)`, `curl_errno($ch)`, `curl_getinfo($ch)`, `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1)` and so on. That's how you find out that something has actually happened.